# Ecological Covariate for a meta-analysis on reading and bilingual learners

Tags: anova, meta-analysis

Is it possible to do a meta-analyses on reading intervention studies of bilingual students and include ecological covariates for the analyses?

I think I am a bit confused as what exactly is an example of a ecological covariate?

Also if I am do include an ecological covariate am I then forced to do either an ANOVA?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Let us consider sex as an example. If your studies either studied men or women then including that as a moderator tells you if the effect is different between mean and women. If instead the studies just report the proportion of women then including that tells you the effect of being enrolled in a study with a certain proportion of women which is not the same.

Not sure what you mean by "doing an ANOVA".